# Problems with CPython on MacOS and Apple M1 chip

Tags: python, c++, macos

I recently moved my content to a new Apple M1 laptop running macOS Monterey and I have some problems with a very simple piece of code that tries to call a `Python` function from `C++`. A concrete example is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089716/calling-a-python-function-from-c).

I installed a new version of `Python 3.9.10` via `Homebrew`, but it seems it is not being *detected* by my compiler since I get the following errors:

```
surrutiaquir$ g++ -o main_ctp_fN_grid ctp_fN_grid.cpp -lgsl -lm -lgslcblas -std=c++11
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_PyDict_GetItemString", referenced from:
      _main in ctp_fN_grid-2fc2a2.o
  "_PyImport_Import", referenced from:
      _main in ctp_fN_grid-2fc2a2.o
  "_PyImport_ImportModule", referenced from:
      _main in ctp_fN_grid-2fc2a2.o
  "_PyList_Append", referenced from:
      _main in ctp_fN_grid-2fc2a2.o
  "_PyModule_GetDict", referenced from:
      _main in ctp_fN_grid-2fc2a2.o
  "_PyObject_CallObject", referenced from:
      _main in ctp_fN_grid-2fc2a2.o
  "_PyObject_GetAttrString", referenced from:
      _main in ctp_fN_grid-2fc2a2.o
  "_PyString_FromString", referenced from:
      _main in ctp_fN_grid-2fc2a2.o
  "_Py_Finalize", referenced from:
      _main in ctp_fN_grid-2fc2a2.o
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
      _main in ctp_fN_grid-2fc2a2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm really confused about this issue, so any guidance would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `ctp_fN_grid-2fc2a2.o` is an `x86_64` architecture object file. You're attempting to link with it when your program is `arm64` architecture.

Comment: Thanks, @Brandon. I got that part, but I'm struggling with the solution. My laptop is a mess right now—apologies in advance.